# How to set browser 'Authorization' header?

Tags: node.js, express, browser, jwt, http-headers

I understand how to secure my API routes, and how to validate requests by interpreting the JWT that are passed along in their `Autorization` headers. What I don't understand, however, is how to do this for a browser.

**How can I set a user's headers, such that his following requests will pass along the JWT my server gave him?**

Currently, when the user submits his email and password, an async Axios request is made to the API that validates his input and returns a JWT. I store this token and I try to set the browser header before redirecting the browser back home.

**Server.js does not receive that header. What am I doing wrong?**

The middleware that logs the headers only logs the following:

```
{
  host: 'localhost:8080',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:93.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/93.0',
  accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
  'accept-language': 'en-GB',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
  dnt: '1',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  referer: 'http://localhost:8080/auth/login',
  'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
  'sec-fetch-user': '?1'
}
```

Server.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const cors = require('cors')
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config({path:__dirname+'/config/.env'})
const app = express()

// Import routes
const routes = {
    frontend: {
        index: require('./App/Routes/route.index'),
        auth: require('./App/Routes/route.auth')
    },
    api: {
        auth: require('./API/Routes/route.auth'),
        users: require('./API/Routes/route.users'),
    }
}

// View engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'App/Views'))
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

// Middleware
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/App/Public')))
const { checkToken } = require('./Middleware/checkToken')

app.use((req, res, next)=>{
    console.log(req.headers) // this does not show the 'Authorization' header
    next()
})

// API routes
app.use('/api/auth', routes.api.auth)
app.use('/api/users', checkToken, routes.api.users)

// Front end routes
app.use('/auth', routes.frontend.auth)
app.use('/', routes.frontend.index) // I want to secure this route too, and redirect any request without a valid JWT to '/auth/login'

// Server
app.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log('Server running...')
})
```

login.ejs

```
<body> 

    // some HTML ...

</body>

<script>

    // submit 
    const submitForm = async () => {
        // Catch user input
        const data = {
            email: $('form #email').val(),
            password: $('form #password').val()
        }
        // submit input
        try {
            const response = await axios.post('/api/auth/login', data)
            const auth = response.headers.authorization
            if (!auth) throw response.data.err
            // save Token
            token = auth.split(' ')[1]
            localStorage.setItem("access_token", token)
            let h = new Headers()
            h.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
            // redirect home
            return window.location.replace("/")
        } catch (error) {
            return console.log(error)
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Your `let h = new Headers()` does nothing, and goes out of scope soon as this client code finishes.  You should be setting the authorization header on *requests* after you've logged in, using the token you set in localStorage.

Comment: Can you explain how I should do that?